# How to get string type of data_type from Autodesk Platform Services?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I have a problem when I try get file model.sdb from Autodesk Platform Services and query string of data_type. My problem is I want to know data_type of enum number is string or double or any string type, I don't know any api to mapping number enum number with string or double. Any help is appreciated !
[image]
this is schema example for that :

```
 },
    {
        "id": 33,
        "name": "Elevation",
        "category": "Constraints",
        "data_type": 3,
        "data_type_context": "autodesk.unit.unit:millimeters-1.0.1",
        "description": null,
        "display_name": "Elevation",
        "flags": 0,
        "display_precision": 1,
        "forge_parameter": null
    },
```

I expecting I can get string of data_type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data_type` enum has the following values:

```
Unknown                 = 0,
Boolean,
Integer,
Double,

/* Special types */
Blob                    = 10,
DbKey, /* reprensets a link to another object in the database, using database internal ID */

/* String types */
String                  = 20,
LocalizableString, 
DateTime,       /* ISO 8601 date */
GeoLocation,    /* LatLonHeight - ISO6709 Annex H string, e.g: "+27.5916+086.5640+8850/" for Mount Everest */
Position        /* "x y z w" space separated string representing vector with 2,3 or 4 elements*/
```

Comment: Hi @Petr Broz, how I can find full detail document for that ?

Comment: Since this is an internal attribute, there's no external documentation.

Comment: Thank you. Can I know what is the type of number 2 ?
__categoryId__  CategoryId   2  -2000080

Comment: The enum I listed in the answer is regular C++, so 0 is `Unknown`, 1 is `Boolean`, 2 is `Integer`, 3 is `Double`, 10 is `Blob`, 11 is `DbKey`, 20 is `String`, 21 is `LocalizableString`, etc.